# Moss 2007 Backup and Recovery

Tags: backup, sharepoint, backup-restoration

What are the best solutions for disaster recovery of a Moss farm? Outside of Microsoft's Data Protection manager, what is there?

Comment: Dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/140/sharepoint-2007-backup-solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this comprehensive blog post by SharePoint Joel: [SharePoint Backup Restore, High Availability, and Disaster Recovery](http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2007/03/09/sharepoint-backup-restore-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery.aspx) which has a lot of advice and lots of links to further reading (whitepapers, technical articles, and more blog posts).

If you're going to implement some kind of backup strategy, remember not to plan a backup strategy - plan a restore strategy based around your RTO and RPO (basically how quickly do you want to be able to restore, with how much allowable data loss) and then figure out what backups you need to be able to take to achieve that.

Most important thing? Once you've put together your DR strategy, test it to make sure it works the way you want.

Hope this helps.